# How to extract files from Azure Pipeline artifacts using Power Automate

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, power-automate

I currently have a yaml **Azure Pipeline** that generates Excel files as artifacts and I would like to upload them to a **SharePoint** folder.
I would like to achieve this using **Power Automate**.

I understand how to run my Power Automate flow when the pipeline finishes.
My issue is about understanding **how to extract the Excel files from Azure Pipeline artifacts using Power Automate** to then push them to SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have tested, there is no action in Power Automate to retrieve pipeline artifacts. Since Azure DevOps itself is an automation tool,  we can upload the Excel files onto SharePoint folder directly **during** a pipeline agent job.

We can use the 3rd-party extension [Upload files to SharePoint Online - Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=halliba.az-pipelines-2-sharepoint) to upload `.xls` files from the working directory on the pipeline agent onto the SharePoint target folder; see for more details on how the task authenticates access to SharePoint against App registration in Azure AD.

Here is my sample pipeline  for your refence, together with the API permission settings of my app registration that is used by the pipeline task to authenticate access to SharePoint.

```
variables:
- group: ARM
- name: CurrentTime
  value : $[ format('{0:yyyy}-{0:MM}-{0:dd} {0:HH}:{0:mm}:{0:ss}', pipeline.startTime) ]

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

jobs:
- job: Prep
  steps:
  - checkout: none
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host "Current Time is $(currentTime)"
      Write-Host "Tenant Id is $(TenantId)"
      Write-Host "Client Id is $(ClientId)"
    displayName: List variables
  - powershell: |
      $data = [PSCustomObject]@{
        TimeStamp = "$(CurrentTime)"
        ProjectName = "$(System.TeamProject)"
        PipelineName = "$(Build.DefinitionName)"
        DefinitionId = "$(System.DefinitionId)"
        BuildId = "$(Build.BuildId)"
      }
      $data | Export-Csv -Path "BuildData.csv" -NoTypeInformation
      Write-Host "Files in $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"
      tree $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) /F /A
    displayName: Generate csv file
  - powershell: |
      Install-Module ImportExcel -Scope CurrentUser -Force
      Import-Csv -Path "BuildData.csv" | Export-Excel -Path "$(Build.DefinitionName)-$(Build.BuildId)-1.xls" -WorksheetName "BuildInfo"
      Import-Csv -Path "BuildData.csv" | Export-Excel -Path "$(Build.DefinitionName)-$(Build.BuildId)-2.xls" -WorksheetName "BuildInfo"
      Write-Host "Files in $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"
      tree $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) /F /A
    displayName: Generate xls file
  - task: az-pipelines-2-sharepoint@0
    displayName: Upload the xls files from System.DefaultWorkingDirectory to SharePoint site
    inputs:
      tenantId: '$(TenantId)'
      clientId: '$(ClientId)'
      clientSecret: '$(ClientSecret)'
      driveId: 'https://$(SharePointOnline).sharepoint.com/sites/AzureDevOpsTeamSite/Shared%20Documents/'
      targetFolder: 'AzureDevOpsExcel'
      sourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
      contents: '**/*.xls'
      conflictBehaviour: 'replace'
      cleanTargetFolder: false
      flattenFolders: false
      failOnEmptySource: false
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi @Batesias, Have you got a chance to check my answer below to upload xls files to SharePoint folder during pipeline agent job? Hope it can resolve your query and benefit other users. Cheers!

Comment: Hi, yes I had already seen this extension, however I'm trying the Power Automate route because I can't currently add extensions in my Azure DevOps organization.